# Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I am experiencing an Error within **nouns[i] = SearchKeywords(words, sentences);** every time I run my program. What should I do?

*I edited to include the SearchKeywords method. I am trying to find all words that have "a" and "an" before them.

Error is,
**Error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'**

```
    string[] SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string[] sentence){

    int[] location = new int[sentence.Length];

    foreach (string word in keywords)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length;i++ )
        {
            string[] nouns = new string[i];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence[i]))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                location[i] = sentence[i].IndexOf(word);

                nouns[i] = sentence[i].Substring(location[i]);

                if (nouns[i].Contains(word)) return nouns;
            }
        }

    }
    return sentence;

   string[] checkForIndefinite()
   {
       string input = txtEntry.Text;

       string text = lbltxtOutput.Text;

       Tools tool = new Tools();    

       List<string> words = new List<string>();
       words.Add("an");
       words.Add("a");

       foreach(string sentence in GetWords(text))
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
           {
               string[] nouns = new string[i];
               string[] sentences = new string[i];
               sentences[i] = sentence;

               **nouns[i] = SearchKeywords(words, sentences);**

              return nouns;

           }
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Comment: What is that error? Mention it here.

Comment: What Type does SearchKeywords method return? I assume string[]?

Comment: `SearchKeywords` is returning an array of strings, which you are trying to assign to a (single) string variable. Obviously, you can't do that. It can't really be fixed without knowing what your goal for this code is.

Comment: Do you think you could provide compilable code?

Comment: I edited to include the SearchKeywords method. I am trying to find all words that have "a" and "an" before them.

Comment: You really seem to be mixing up strings and arrays of strings in your code. Am I right in saying that `SearchKeywords` should return the all the words in the `sentence` array that have any of the `keywords` in the previous word?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is what you need:

```
string[] SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string[] sentence)
{
    return
        sentence
            .Zip(sentence.Skip(1), (w0, w1) => new { w0, w1 })
            .Where(ww => keywords.Contains(ww.w0))
            .Select(ww => ww.w1)
            .ToArray();
}

string[] checkForIndefinite()
{
    var input = txtEntry.Text;
    var text = lbltxtOutput.Text;
    var words = new List<string>() { "an", "a" };
    return SearchKeywords(words, GetWords(text));
}
```

Comment: This is giving me an error on line `.Where(ww => keywords.Contains(w0))` saying that, "The name `w0` does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Have you got `using System.Linq;` at the top?

Comment: @JohnHodge - It worked just fine for me. I run every answer in LINQPad before posting.

Comment: I have `using System.Linq;`. Here the entire program if you want to take a look: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/KL8QeX](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KL8QeX)

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same result in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnHodge - I don't know how but somewhere from copying from LINQPad to SO the text `ww.` got dropped. I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `SearchKeywords` function is an `string[]` and the `nouns[i]` is a `string` and simply you cannot assign and `string[]` value to a `string`. So You may what to try something like this:

```
List<string> nouns = new List<string>();

//foreach loop
    //    for loop

        nouns.AddRange(SearchKeywords(words, sentences));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] indefinites = checkForIndefinite();
        foreach (string s in indefinites)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }


    static string[] SearchKeywords(List<string> keywords, string sentence)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<string> nouns = new List<string>();

        string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

        foreach (string keyword in keywords)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++ )
            {
                if (words[i] == keyword)
                {
                    if (i+1 < words.Length && !nouns.Contains(words[i+1]))
                    {
                        nouns.Add(words[i+1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nouns.ToArray();
    }

   static string[] checkForIndefinite()
   {
       string sentence = "This is not an interesting sentence to use to test a program";

       string text = string.Empty;   

       List<string> words = new List<string>();
       words.Add("an");
       words.Add("a");

       return SearchKeywords(words, sentence);

   }
}
```

This compiles and returns the following:

```
interesting
program
```